# IN and ON again

Tags: prepositions

The data was IN my phone or ON my phone?

Well, IN being generally more of a 'containment' preposition, I would think its usage here is okay, and the phone is perceived as `bag`. However, I wonder which preposition would end up being the one used because sometimes things in English have both a 'contained' property (where, if I'm not mistaken, we generally use `in`) and a `loaded` property (where we use `on`). I'm thinking than that my question ends up being also "how do the English perceive things that were saved to a phone? as put [e.g. in a bag] or loaded [e.g. on a bus]?"

Comment: Whichever one you prefer.  Outside of technical circles, any rules someone might tell you for this are quite weak.

Comment: These are issues with Spanish and English. In English, we say data on my phone. In Spanish, we say: en mi telefono.

Comment: Definitely! the more Latin based languages lack the concept of "on", so the "en" is used for lotsa "in" and "on" (and "at"!) cases :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say **on** the computer/phone and **in** the computer/phone are equally common.

With a particular app/system **in** is more likely; in Sharepoint, in the database. But where it is stored physically is generally **on**; on disk, on tape, on a USB flash drive.

Answer (score 1):

Data are saved **in** a register **on** a device. Thus, considering a phone mainly a register for contacts and messages, that information is saved **in** the phone, considering the phone as a device, the information is saved **on** the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, "in the phone" sounds better to me but, both in and on were in the academic papers (used google academic). So, I believe both can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to distinguish the use of on/in, is whether the information is currently being accessed - or, is stored in memory. For example:

**"Can you get the information from your assistant?"**

***"He's on my phone."*** (I am currently speaking to him)

***"He's in my phone."*** (I have his contact information/I will contact him)

**"Do you have the blueprints handy?**

***"They're in my computer."*** (I can access them, if needed.)

***"They're on my computer."*** (If you look at my monitor, you can see them.)